# Why stop app after play video via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I try play video via intent. I use this method :

```
   private void play_video() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/nabege" + File.separator + "video"
        + File.separator + videoFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);}
```

When end played video stop app.

```
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449): Activity com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$6@41b61bf8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$6@41b61bf8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:837)
09-25 15:47:02.772: E/ActivityThread(31449):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:608)
```

I search in Internet and I knew that I most use registerReceiver()  and unregisterreceiver() methods .Now I do not understand that how to use this two methods. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace is from another app, not yours:

```
Activity com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$6@41b61bf8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

You did not write an activity named `com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity`. That is the third-party app that is playing your video. You are seeing a bug in that app, apparently. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Perhaps send the creator of that app a message?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean .  You think, what's the problem?

Comment: @programer138200: You have not shown a problem in **your app**. You have shown a problem in **another app**.

Comment: I'm running a video file via Intent. After the end of  video playback ,my app stopped. I do not think that is the problem of video player program . I debug app and not found any exception

Comment: @programer138200: "After the end of video playback ,my app stopped" -- what does "stopped" mean?

Comment: show this message that : unfortunately you app has stoped

Comment: @programer138200: You may get one of those from the crash in the other app. If you are sure that it is *your* app that is crashing, then there will be a stack trace associated with *your* app.